# XAML how do you convert this to a Resource instead of have a long Button template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have here my Button and it has some animation custom style, but I have 6 of those and I hate looking at the entire xaml with each button having 41 lines

```
<Button Width="250" Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="btnShutdown" IsDefault="False" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Width="250" Background="Red">
        <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="120" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Width="120" Source="/SystemPowerShortcuts;component/image_res/shutdown.png" />
        <TextBlock Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,95,0,6" Text="Shutdown" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" Width="66" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Normal" />
    </Grid>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="btnShutdown_Transform" Angle="0" />
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="btnShutdown_Transform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        To="-1" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="btnShutdown_Transform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        To="-5" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="btnShutdown_Transform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

how do you convert this as a resource so I don't have a very very long xaml code?

The Buttons has custom image and a text but has the same animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be best off creating a custom control.  This way you can set up dependency properties to control the source of you image etc.  If you just make it a style in a resource dictionary then your stuck with the same image etc.  See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235.aspx) for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource dictionary (Add New Item -> Resource Dictionary), then make a style and template for your buttons as so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="120" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="btnTransform" Angle="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Red">
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Height="120" Width="250">
                            <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="120"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill"
                                   Width="120"
                                   Source="/SystemPowerShortcuts;component/image_res/shutdown.png" />
                            <TextBlock Height="19" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Margin="14,95,0,6" Text="Shutdown"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"
                                       Width="66" Foreground="White"
                                       FontWeight="Normal" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="btnTransform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            To="-1" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="btnTransform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            To="-5" Duration="0:0:0.1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="btnShutdown_Transform"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                            To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then add your resource dictionary to your App.xaml file:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="FileNameHere.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then for each button put

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" ... />
```

Comment: You would have to assume he wants different images etc for each buttoon.  In which case a custom control would be better than a style

Comment: Well each button has a custom Image and Text. How do I do that?

Comment: See my answer post.  It has link to a blog which shows you how to do it